# Building a gui which is dynamic at runtime

Tags: java, xml, swing, xul

I am trying to work on a utility in which my requirement is to have "editable" gui elements for each instance. When i say "editable" it means, I am looking for something where the user can add some textfield or delete some text field at his will.

I was wondering, if there is some XML > Java available? So that addition deletion of any gui element would add/delete them at next run.

I saw couple of framework like CoolSWT etc. but its dead!

Comment: Read in file (XML, JSON, whatever), parse, build UI to match. Or do you mean you're looking for a framework that already does this for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a list of frameworks which let you build a GUI in a declarative way in XML:

http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-user-interface-toolkits

[XUI](http://www.xoetrope.com/xui) and [Wazaabi](http://wazaabi.org/) seem to have been really interesting but are not really maintained anymore since a couple of years.

The only one which seems to be be still kicking is [SwiXml](http://www.swixml.org/).

Sadly, I think JavaFX killed these projects...

Comment: It appears JavaFX 2 let you build GUI in XML, too.